# Heroku Scheduler - why enqueue long-running jobs

Tags: django, heroku, system-administration

The [Heroku Scheduler documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#longrunning_jobs) says:

> Scheduled jobs are meant to execute short running tasks or enqueue longer running tasks into a background job queue. Anything that takes longer than a couple of minutes to complete should use a worker process to run

If the Scheduler starts a new dyno for these jobs and the cost is the same for a dyno vs. a worker, what is the advantage to adding a task to the queue and having a worker process run it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is an architectural best practice to only schedule, and not execute, interval tasks on the scheduler task (or your own custom clock process). The motivation for this is explained in the [scheduled jobs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) article but, to summarize, you want your scheduler process/task to be as light-weight as possible since there should only be one of them. When you start overloading scheduling with execution you often run into schedule conflicts and erratic behavior.

Imagine that one interval job hangs, or takes much longer than expected. If your intervals are tight enough this will start causing a backlog and future intervals could be pushed back or skipped all together.

Also, it is just wise to keep component responsibilities as separated as possible - not having a single component be responsible for orthogonal tasks. This is a common design practice which is reflected in the scheduled job use-case by keeping scheduling and execution independent.

Best practices aside, if you're in development or bootstrap mode and understand the consequences stated above you can certainly choose to ignore such advice and run everything within the scheduler task. Just be careful for hard to debug job conflicts or apparent duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this is just a recommendation. If you have a task which is ran by Scheduler and you'll run this task manually (in the Heroku administration), you'll get an error - this error is caused by timeout (because each task has limit 30s). But in fact, this task will not be interrupted - the task is gonna be finished correctly.

If you have 1 dyno, so this one dyno use Heroku for your application. If you run some scheduled job, so this dyno gonna be taken be the Scheduler -> if you have long-time running task, your page will be "idle" (not correctly working till the time, when the scheduled job will be finished).

Comment: My understanding is that a new dyno is spun-up for these processes. Per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps. Also, the first link implies there is not a 30s time out